# Windows Server delete files in folder but no permision to delete folder itself

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012-r2, network-share, file-permissions, user-permissions

We have a problem, with permissions on shared folder for out employees.

We have folder lets say Main, with multiple projects (files and folder inside), constantly added and removed. The problem is that it happend that some employee deleted the whole folder accidently.

Now, the thing is, we would like to allow employees to delete any file or folder added or existing in the folder "Main" but no permission to delete whole folder "Main".

Can anybody please help me ? Thank you in advance,...

Comment: I do not have time to write a proper answer, but will give you the hint that you could set the restrictive permissions you need for `main` and set them to only apply to `main` but not subfolders and files. Then you are free to set permissions to subfolders as you see fit but `main` will not be deletable by the common user. Go exploring the GUI and do look up the NTFS permissions documentation.

Answer (score -1):

you may not want to give the FULL CONTROL to the users and use special permissions and deny deleting the MAIN folder and remove inheritance only for the MAIN folder. Remember to do create DELETE permission only for the MAIN folder and not for all subfolders and files. while stopping inheritance don't forget to COPY permission. Otherwise chances are there you may lose entire permission list that you have given and you cannot revert it.